# Android Marshmallow API 25 and below - EXTRA_INITIAL_URI not honored therefore unable to open given folder

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

when trying to use the [now-not-optional-anymore SAF (Storage-Access-Framework)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) to access a given folder on older Android (Marshmallow API 25 or before) the [`EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI) is not honored, therefore not showing the requested folder `uriToLoad` but the generic *Recent* file manager, therefore making the life of users impossible.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Any hint on how to open a given folder on such APIs <= 25?

thanks
nicola

[image]

Comment: Since [that `Intent` extra was only added in API Level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/DocumentsContract#extra_initial_uri), it is not supposed to work on API Level 25 and lower.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare always a privilege to get replies from you! I looked for ways to accomplish this anyway, but I didn't find any, so there's no workaround to get this done? Every day it seems like we're going backward.. Sorry for the rant

Comment: "so there's no workaround to get this done?" -- SAF is not mandatory on those older versions of Android, the way it (nearly) is today. So, do something else for those, such as work with the filesystem and a file-picker library, if you don't like the way SAF behaves prior to getting `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` support.

Comment: Thanks, I [interpreted](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) SAF was mandatory anyway _once_ you target API 30, but I understand this is not the case.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` does not affect devices older than the version. So, having `targetSdkVersion` of `30` has no effect on a device running API Level 25 for example -- that device will behave the same as if the `targetSdkVersion` were `29`. IOW, future Google policies cannot "retcon" behavior of older OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
uriToLoad = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, parsedUri)

parsedUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary[urlEncoded_content]")

urlEncoded_content = UrlEncode(":path")
```

`path` is relative path to sdcard root.